# Laravel: Users birthday resets when user logs on

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have a very strange problem in my Laravel application.

In my application: I have a field where users must enter their date of birth when signing up. It all saves correctly and displays correctly once signed up and logged in for the first time (It automatically signs you in after sign-up). But once you logout and re-login: The birthday date gets reset to today's date. 
And here is where it gets strange: It only happens when I do it on the production server. It's behaving perfectly normal on the local development server.

It only happens to the particular account that logged on, and does not affect all accounts at once.

The production server is ran from Laravel Forge and hosted on DigitalOcean. The production server is running *Ubuntu 18.04* and PHP version 7.2

The local development server is a Windows machine and i'm using whatever *Laragon* comes with.

The version of Laravel used is 5.6

---

Now here is all the code I have surrounding the birthday field:

**Database migration**

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->timestamp('birthday')->after('password');
});
```

**RegisterController.php**

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        ...
        'birthday' => 'required|date_format:d.m.Y',
        ...
    ]);
}

protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        ...
        'birthday' => Carbon::parse($data['birthday'])->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        ...
    ]);
}
```

The LoginController is using the default, untouched login code generated from artisan command `make:auth` in version 5.6 of Laravel.

Here is the controller code for my users preferences where they can change their date of birth in case they miss-entered it during sign-up.

**AccountController.php**
This is the code that grabs the currently logged on user and displays their preferences:

```
public function index() {
    $user = User::find(Auth::id());

    return view('account.account')->withUser($user);
}
```

And this is the part that saves and updates their preferences when they click on save:

```
public function update(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        ...
        'birthday' => 'required|date|before:-15 years'
    ]);

    $user = User::find(Auth::id());

    ...
    $user->birthday = Carbon::parse($request->birthday)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    ...
    $user->save();

    Session::flash('success', 'Din bruker ble oppdatert.');

    return redirect()->route('my.account');
}
```

This is all working perfectly fine, it updates and sets the birthday correctly in the database. It just gets changed to today's date when the user is signed in. Does not happen with local development server, and only in the production server. Which makes it very difficult to debug properly.

Let me know if you need any more info. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the type of the column from `timestamp` to `datetime`.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. Still has the same behavior.

Comment: My mistake. My migration didn't actually update the columns datatype. I had to ssh into the production server and manually run an SQL statement to update it. Once I did this, it now seems to behave. Thank you :)